# using serversocket to receive and play audio in android?

Tags: android, voip

I have an android client app from which i record audio from mic and send it to an socket. Now I want to build another app that will create a ServerSocket and listen to the audio from the mic and play it.

Will anybody guide me on that?

Comment: Maybe you can take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769293/peer-to-peer-audio-calling-on-android-voice-breaks-and-lagdelay-in-receiving

Comment: The question is too broad/vague. What specific problem have you run into when writing the receiver app?

Comment: @Michael i don't know how to read data from serversocket and play it.